# nodeJS Paypal REST API to revise plan give broken but working link

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, paypal, backend

I'm trying to integrate Paypal into my app in NodeJS. I'm using REST API since the official  npm packet is deprecated.
Let's suppose I have a product with two plans, `planA` and `planB`, necessary for recurring payments like subscriptions. Suppose a customer subscribe to planA, which costs 10$. After a while, he wants to switch  to planB, which  costs 20$, to unlock premium content in the platform.

I found the API: `POST/v1/billing/subscriptions/{id}/revise`
with which one should be able to send the planID `planB` to switch to it. You can also send `effective_time` field to specify when the change is effective. After calling this API, Paypal reply with 6 links, and I use the first (`approve`) to redirect the customer to Paypal domain to confirm it's will to switch the plan. After the user login, confirm and click "Accept and subscribe" to the new plan, the page always give me the following error: `Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.`
, despite the plan change goes fine (I can verify it through dashboard).

I'm wondering what can I do to avoid that error.
I want to clarify that in the settings, through the dashboard, under `Account settings` -> `Website payments` -> `Website preferences`, I temporarily have the option `Block non-encrypted website payment` to `Off`.
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting "Block non-encrypted website payment" is not relevant to this issue, and will have no effect. It applies exclusively to [legacy HTML-only payments](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#link-encryptedwebsitepaymentsewp), which you should not concern yourself with.

---

Edit: ah yes, a redirect integration requires an application_context with a return_url.  For usage with the SDK, no redirect_url is used, hence why the field is not required by the API.

Previous answer follows:

---

The issue you describe seems to be a problem with the PayPal site, and possibly only occurs in sandbox mode or with certain browsers/cookies. You can test as desired and contact PayPal's support if needed.

It is also possible to do a revise with the JS SDK rather than a redirect.  For a client-side-only integration (no API), this can be done using `actions.subscription.revise`. Search for that text within [the SDK reference](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/#link-buttons).

To combine the JS SDK with the API call you are using, have your button code fetch the revised subscription ID from your server.  Here is a sample for a create, which you can adapt to be a revise as it's essentially the same thing (you'd just likely be using a `/revise` endpoint /path/on/your/server)

```
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=..........&amp;vault=true&amp;intent=subscription"></script>

  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

  <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          label:'subscribe'  //Optional text in button
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
          return fetch('/path/on/your/server/paypal/subscription/create/', {
              method: 'post'
          }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
          }).then(function(serverData) {
              console.log(serverData);
              return serverData.id;
          });
      },

      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      /*  Optional: At this point, notify your server of the activated subscription...

          fetch('/path/on/your/server/paypal/subscription/activated/' + data.subscriptionID , {
              method: 'post'
          }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
          }).then(function(serverData) {
              //
          });
      */
          //You could additionally subscribe to a webhook for the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED event (just in case), as well as other future subscription events
          //Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions

          // Show a message to the buyer, or redirect to a success page
          alert('You successfully subscribed! ' + data.subscriptionID);
      }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Preston PHX, your snippet helped me anyway.
I think I solved the problem (it goes like this, a problem hits you for days and when you ask for help you solve it... Forgive me).
The body of the revise API should include the application_context field, with inside a return_url and a cancel_url. In this way, it works properly! Thank you anyway for your answer and your time.

PS I would have liked your answer, but I'm new on Stack Overflow and I don't have enough reputation to do so.